# Auto generate age when date is set using datepicker - Android Xamarin

Tags: android, datepicker, xamarin.android

how to auto generate the and edittext when the datepicker is set?

my xml file look like this:

```
        <TextView
            android:text="Birthdate:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/in_bDate"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:spinnersShown="true" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Age:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/in_age"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

and my cs file looks like this:

```
        DatePicker bDate = FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.in_bDate);
        EditText age = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.in_age);

        bDate.Click += delegate {
            var year = DateTime.Now.Year;
            int auto_age = year - bDate.Year;
            age.SetText(auto_age.ToString(), TextView.BufferType.Editable);
        };
```

edit: changed the methods in setting the content of age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePicker` needs to be initialized after being created and you can pass an DateChangeEventListener to [DatePicker.Init](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.DatePicker.Init/p/System.Int32/System.Int32/System.Int32/Android.Widget.DatePicker+IOnDateChangedListener/) method and inside the DateChangeListener, you can set the `TextView`'s Text:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    public DatePicker datePicker;
    public EditText age;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        datePicker = FindViewById<DatePicker>(Resource.Id.in_bDate);
        age = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.in_age);
        DateChangeEventHandler handler = new DateChangeEventHandler(this);
        datePicker.Init(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, handler);

    }


    public class DateChangeEventHandler :Java.Lang.Object, DatePicker.IOnDateChangedListener
    {
        Activity activity;

        public DateChangeEventHandler(Activity a)
        {
            activity = a;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }

        public void OnDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            (activity as MainActivity).age.Text = view.DateTime.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
private String getUserAge() {

    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    dob.setTime(mCurrentUser.dateBirthday);

    int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if (today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
        age--;
    }

    return Integer.toString(age) + " yo";
}
```